# Why am I getting an error when I try to send an Ajax query with the Intel XDK?

Tags: javascript, ajax, intel-xdk

I am using the Intel XDK to create some applications. I need to send an Ajax query to a handler, but the application gives me an error when I send. The query is "pending" in debugging. But in the emulator the Intel XDK query successfully completed. Where is the problem?

There is my JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "mysite.com/php/getList.php",
            data: { "faculty": 6 }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) 
              {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            })
            .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
                  {
                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
```

Comment: Lead the `url` with `//` at least -- `url: "//mysite.com/php/getList.php"`. Without that, `mysite.com` is assumed to be a *directory* rather than the host.

Answer (score 2):

It may be failing because of cross-origin policy. 
Either your API should support JSONP or have Allow Access Origin * in header.

Or you can include these script tags in your index.html file and then build the app in Intel XDK:

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script src="xhr.js"></script>
```

More info here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

Answer (score 0):

Try firing ajax this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "mysite.com/php/getList.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "faculty": 6 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
```